# JSTL. How to call a function from <script> in c:set jstl tag?

Tags: javascript, jstl

I just need something like this:

```
<c:set var="cls" value="${myFunc(param)}"/>

.....

<script>
    function myFunc(param) {
        if(param == true) {
            return "aaa";
        } else {
            return "bbb";
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I try it then get this error:

> org.apache.jasper.el.JspELException: /script.jsp(22,12) '${myFunc()}'
>   Function [:myFunc] not found

Comment: I don't know what you want to achieve exactly ?? Can you elaborate a little ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is what you are trying to do, possible??

Answer to this in one word would be **NO**...

Let's dive into the reason, hint is here.. JSTL (JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library).. see the word 'Server'. Yes.

The JSP pages gets compiled as like your Java files. Once the compilation is successful, it can be then sent as a response and then browser renders this response and displays the page.

JavaScript : is a client side programming language which means codes in JavaScript are run by the browser not by the server.

When compiler compiles Jsp file, it only plays around the Scriptlet and JSTL part, and rest of the code (I mean the rest of HTML, CSS and JS code) is just a piece of string.

Now, imagine a situation in your code, while Java compiler is trying to compile it finds that `myFunc` must be a method but where to look for?

It cannot see it as a javascript function, because javascript runs only in browser not in server side. And hence, you are not able to set the value of `cls` variable, because `myFunc` is unknown for Java.

Hope this helps you understand JSP and Server Side working.

Keeping above things in mind, try some better approach to solve your problem.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thx.